# Challenge with ProcessStartInfo Arguments ncftpget

Tags: c#, t-sql, processstartinfo

There are several solutions posted to that explain how to pass multiple arguments to ProcessStartInfo to run a DOS command with more than one argument.  None of them work in this particular case.

Trying to run ncftpget from inside a c# application - passing multiple arguments to the executable using an exact string literal (@"arg1 arg2 arg3").

What's happening is that the argument list is long enough that it is getting truncated, but not where I would expect (at the end).

So I pass something like:

```
Program = "ncftpget"
Arguments = @"-f host.cfg D:\ServerBackups\Windows6 2012_01_28_SQLBackupFile.bak"
```

And what ncftp gets is

```
-f host.cfg D:\ServerBackups\Windows6 ackupfile.bak
```

If instead of calling ncftpget directly, I write a bat file and execute that, it works.

The odd thing is that from T/SQL using XP_CMDShell - I am calling ncftpget with arguments much longer than this.  It is as if there is some environment variable that says "parameters can only be so long, and I am going to truncate them from the beginning, not the end"

I've tried quoting the arguments, makes no difference, same behavior.

Of course if Microsoft actually had a decent ftp solution... that used the correct mode...but that's an old rant that they will never fix.

Comment: Very odd that it would do that. Have you tried quoting the path in your argument?

Comment: `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` wont do what you need?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: The behaviour you mention is not a part of ProcessStartInfo, rather you have a bug in your code somewhere truncating that particular string. Post your code and someone will point out the bug for you I'm sure.